# What's Mysql fastest way to delete a database content?

Tags: mysql, freebsd

mysql fastest way to delete a database content on freebsd? please help
i've tried to delete from navicat (400,000+ lines),
but in a hour... just 100,000 was deleted
I haven't phpmyadmin

Comment: to delete all content of a table: truncate: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete everything in a table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_you_want_to_nuke
```

To delete certain rows, you have two options:

1. Follow these steps:

   - Create a temporary table using `CREATE TABLE the_temp_table LIKE current_table`
   - Drop all of the indexes on the temp table.
   - Copy the records you want to *keep* with `INSERT INTO the_temp_table SELECT * FROM current_table WHERE ...`
   - `TRUNCATE TABLE current_table`
   - `INSERT INTO current_table SELECT * FROM the_temp_table`
   - To speed this option up, you may want to drop all indexes from `current_table` before the final `INSERT INTO`, then recreate them after the `INSERT`. MySQL is much faster at indexing existing data than it is at indexing on the fly.
2. The option you're currently trying: `DELETE FROM your_table WHERE whatever_condition`. You probably need to break this into chunks using the `WHERE` condition or `LIMIT`, so you can batch it and not bog down the server forever.

Which is better/faster depends on lots of things, mostly the ratio of deleted records to retained records and the number of indexes involved. As always, **test this carefully** before doing it on a live database, as both `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` will *permanently* destroy data.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can't truncate a table that is referenced by a foreign key constraint